# Javascript, change value of new created object

Tags: javascript, html

i think i got a Problem with async Code.

My form with a select:

```html
<tr>
<td>Genre</td>
 <td>
  <div class="styled-select">
  <select id="Genre" name="Genre" onchange="showUntergenre(this.value)">
   <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
   $_sql_Genre = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM tbl_genre ");
   While ($Genre_result = mysql_fetch_array($_sql_Genre)){  
    $genre_id=$Genre_result[0];  
    $genre_name=$Genre_result[1];
    echo"<option value='$genre_id'>$genre_name</option>";
   } 
  </select>
  </div>
 </td>
 <input type="hidden" name="GenreHidden" id="GenreHidden" value="$genre">
 <td>
  <div id="txtHint"></div>
 </td>
 <input type="hidden" name="UntergenreHidden" id="UntergenreHidden" value="$untergenre">
</tr><tr>
```

Now i set the value of the hidden fields and go in this form. The following javascript Code will be executed:

```js
window.onload = selectSelectBox("Genre");
handleGenre();
handleUntergenre();
```

I select an entry in the selectbox.

```js
function selectSelectBox(object){
 var selectBox = document.getElementById(object);
 var value = document.getElementById(object + "Hidden").value;
 if (selectBox != null && value != "0"){
  selectBox.selectedIndex = value;
 }
}
```

I want the value of the hidden field.

```js
function handleGenre(){
 genreValue = document.getElementById("GenreHidden").value;
 if (genreValue != "0"){
  showUntergenre(document.getElementById("GenreHidden").value);
 }
}
```

Now i do a SELECT on my db to get the values for a new selectbox.

```js
function showUntergenre(str, selected) {
 if (str==0){
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
 } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
   document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","getUntergenre.php?genre="+str+"&selected="+selected,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Snippet of that php Page:

```html
echo "<select id='Untergenre' name='Untergenre'>";
 echo "<option value='0'></option>";
 $i =1;
 $_sql_Untergenre = mysql_query ("SELECT ".$Genre."_bezeichnung FROM tbl_genre_".$Genre);
 While ($UnterGenre = mysql_fetch_array($_sql_Untergenre)){      
  if ($i == $selected)
   echo "<option value='".$i."' selected='selected'>".$UnterGenre[0]."</option>";
  else
   echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$UnterGenre[0]."</option>";    
  $i++;
}
```

Now ive got a new selectbox in my form and i want to select my desired entry, located in a hidden field.

```js
function handleUntergenre(){
  untergenreValue = document.getElementById("UntergenreHidden").value;
  if (untergenreValue != "0"){
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("Untergenre");
    console.log("!!!!! this selectBox is always null, except in the debugger !!!!: " + selectBox);
    selectBox.selectedIndex = untergenreValue;
  }
}
```

This works only in the Browser debugger, otherwise "selectBox" is null.

I dont know if anyone can help me here, but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have several other issues in your code:

- You *execute* a function when assigning to `window.onload`, instead of just passing the function to it. This is not what you wanted to happen.
- The function `showUntergenre` has two parameters, but you only call it with one (both from the HTML attribute as in the main JS code), so `selected` will always be undefined, yet you add its value to a URL.

Now to the main issue:

Indeed you are trying to find the `Untergenre` select box before it is available. You need to wait for the http request to come back with the response, and only then look for the select box.

One way to do this, is to use a callback system. I will provide that here, but you should definitely consider using promises and the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

Let the function `showUntergenre` accept a callback function (`cb`) as argument, which it will call when the additional content has been loaded:

```
function showUntergenre(str, selected, cb) {
    // ...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            if (cb) cb(); // call the callback (if provided)
        }
        // ...
```

Now make sure that callback feature is used, so do the same in `handleGenre`. Note that I do not know what you intend to pass for value for `selected`, so please provide the value you want it to have:

```
function handleGenre(cb){
    genreValue = document.getElementById("GenreHidden").value;
    if (genreValue != "0"){
        var selected = .......;
        showUntergenre(document.getElementById("GenreHidden").value, selected, cb);
    }
}
```

... and in the call of `handleGenre`:

```
window.onload = function () { // Pass a function!!
    selectSelectBox("Genre");
    handleGenre(handleUntergenre); // here we define the real callback
};
```

This is the idea... Now you'll probably have to adjust it to your actual needs.